# Conditional Split transform on Text File

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have this sort of data in a text file which I want to split based on one column. I have tried this in SSIS using a conditional transform. My data is as follows

```
CSH1364300   NTT Nissan Mhangura                          NISSAN              NISSAN 3.0T/D DJ55       ADNJ550000A000337   J55-3374  FRX391NW  85M19690            1         1  13/01/2012Mr    Mairosi Melows                                       0182939060     0832626733     0832626733   E     Mr Xioang Ching                                     NULL                                         Samuel            199396PRIVATE BAG X1                Renkers NORTH                                           1741      2400          1349          ?             55            ?             3804          
CSH1364300   NTT Nissan Chivhu                          NISSAN              NAVARA 2.5 4X2 N30       MNTNCGD40Z0002046   N300000211HHS788NW  85M19910            1         1  13/01/2012Mr          Forest Gump                                0187862724     NULL           NULL         A     Mairos  Motors                                   null                                         Samuel            85251 Stoner Road                                                  Charlotteville                 4900      1395          14941.5       ?             ?             ?             16336.5       
MTP90961     NORTHERN MOTORS CHITOMBO                       DISCOVERY 4         LANDROVER DISCOLDS       SALLAAAF3BA580608   BA580608  DYT433FS  55W84243            23        0  16/01/2012Mr    M     George Jungle                               |              NULL           0824691669   E     JUGGLE CANTEEN/A                            sparkywp@mweb.co.za                          MAIDEI HAVATIDI   24496 
CSH92041     NORTHERN MOTORS CHITOMBO                       Volvo               S40 2006 Model 544       YV1MS685162192177             BM40PYGP  55D10150            18        0  16/01/2012Miss  S    Rotheram                                   |              |              0837170017   E     Miss S Simabnegavi                                   NONE GIVEN                                   Sarah Ndipeiwo          108767
CRE1364300   NTT Nissan Chivhu                          NISSAN              NISSAN NP 300 2K09       ADNK090000A000607   K09-6075  HKN637NW  85M19920            1         1  13/01/2012Mnr                                                    0761539867     0761539867     0761539867   A     City Of Valleyland                                 null                                         Samuel           75620 P O Box 495                                                  Chegutu                    2570      829.4         551.19        ?             55            ?             1435.59
```

I want all the rows with NORTHERN MOTORS CHITOMBO  to go onto their own file and the rest to be in another file. My conditional expression is as follows:

```
SUBSTRING([Column 0],14,41) == "NOTHERN MOTORS CHITOMBO"
```

It is not returning desired results. Technology in use BIDS 2008

Comment: Thanks for the edit job. Although the query that's supposed to return the records has a missing R in the word NORTHERN

Comment: In situations like this, I find it helpful to add a derived column transformation in before the conditional split. In your case, my Derived Column would have a new column, `WTF` and it's value would be `SUBSTRING([Column 0],14,41)` Then I can attach a data viewer succeeding that transformation and inspect the value there. It may also be helpful to add a `len(WTF)` column in there as well. This has an added benefit of your conditional split being more clear `(WTF == "NORTHERN MOTORS CHITOMOB)` at the cost of some additional memory

Answer (score 0):

What does "not returning desired results" mean? One obvious problem is that your SUBSTRING expression has "NOTHERN" but the data has "NORTHERN", so it will never match.

I have no idea what column names you have assigned in your data flow, but [Column 0] suggests the first column, not the second. Do you need [Column 1] instead?

Finally, your SUBSTRING() expression is probably incorrect, because the string you want to find is not 41 characters long, it's 24, so SUBSTRING([Column 1], 1, 24) is more likely to be correct.

Comment: Sorry about the fact that the word NORTHERN is missing an N. I have already alluded to that. That's not the issue. This text file is treated as if its one column hence the column 0. So the column has to be as indicated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but still I cannot get the number of rows that meet the criteria being routed to the expected destination

Comment: You still haven't explained exactly what is not working. Are no rows being routed, or only some rows? Or something else completely? Whatever the case, I strongly suggest that you start processing the file as multiple columns, it will be much easier to work with the data that way.

Comment: Sorry about the omission but no rows are being routed to destination that satisfies the condition.

Comment: As I mentioned, the SUBSTRING() parameter for the length of the string appears to be wrong; have you checked it? And have you tried FINDSTRING() instead? And to repeat, I strongly suggest that you treat the data as multiple columns, because in addition to being much easier to work with, you can view the columns in a data viewer for debugging.

Comment: I have since corrected the length parameter. And have also tried this expression as well.(FINDSTRING("NORTHERN MOTORS CHITOMBO", [Column 0],1)) > 0Thanks